# Get TextView size programmatically

Tags: android

**My Code:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("Home");
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mesage_linear1);
    final TextView message = new TextView(getActivity());
    number_view.setText("Long Text");
    int m_width = message.getMeasuredWidth();
    int m_height = message.getMeasuredHeight();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Height : "+m_height+"\nWidth : "+m_width,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return rootView;
}
```

I want to get the height and width of the programmatically created `TextView`.

Output is Height : 0 and Width : 0

Comment: add your `TextiVew` inside `rootView`

Comment: You need to measure the height and width first.
message.measure(MeasureSpec.AT_MOST,MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

after 

 int m_width = message.getMeasuredWidth();
 int m_height = message.getMeasuredHeight();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that point the `View` hasn't been laid out yet. You have to manually measure it (via [`View.measure()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,%20int))) or to wait until it is laid out:

```
textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        int height = textView.getHeight();
        int width = textView.getWidth();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText("Android");
    tv.measure(0, 0);
    tv.getMeasuredWidth();
    tv.getMeasuredHeight(); 
    tv.getTextSize();
```